# react component mounting twice every time

Tags: reactjs

My react component is mounting twice for apparently reason.

[image: This is my app.js]

[image: This is the first picture of my login js]

[image: This is the second picture of my login js]

[image: This is the console picture from where i am checking for the mounting]

Also let me know if i have any other errors whether it be a programming or best practice here.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code. Edit your question and copy the text there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not remounting. Its just rerendering with updated state or props. Every time you update state and props, your component will rerender but with power of hooks it remembers old state value and keeps state among  consequent renders